# Bounding the smallest eigenvalue of an ergodic Markov Chain

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove that the smallest eigenvalue of an ergodic Markov chain is greater than -1. Can we do that using proof by contradiction, i.e. assuming the smallest eigenvalue being -1, etc.? The classical Perron-Frobenius proof does not give an answer since it deals with absolute values.

Comment: What do you mean by "smallest" among complex numbers?

Comment: To be more specific, I want to prove the eigenvalue property as stated in the first page of this paper: http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/stroock91.pdf, i.e. in the case the chain is aperiodic.

Comment: In this specific case the eigenvalues are reals.

Comment: My answer shows that if the chain is ergodic, then $-1$ is not an eigenvalue for $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $P$, let $v$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Since the chain is ergodic, the sequence $P^n$ of matrices converges. Then so does the sequence of numbers 
$\langle v,P^n v\rangle =\lambda^n \|v\|^2$. But this can only happen if $\lambda=1$ or $|\lambda|<1$.